# How to query JSONB member names with spaces in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am running a query on Postgresql 9.4.4 and am having trouble accessing data from a JSONB member which has spaces in the name.

When I run the following query...

```
"SELECT result FROM test"
```

I get the following result

> {"test": 1, "ch0 gain": 2, "ch1 gain": 3}

When I run try to specify a member directly with spaces such as...

```
"SELECT result->'ch0 gain' FROM test"
```

The result is empty, but not the case if I run the following query...

```
"SELECT result->'test' FROM test"
```

Do I have the wrong syntax, or is it just not supported? I'm having trouble finding the answer.

Comment: Make sure you really have just a space there (not other whitespace character). This works for me: `SELECT result->'ch0 gain' FROM (VALUES (jsonb '{"test": 1, "ch0 gain": 2, "ch1 gain": 3}')) test(result)`

Comment: show your table structure and insert query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right **Operator** :

```
Operator    Operand
-------------------
->           int    
->           text   
->>          int    
->>          text   
#>           text[]     
#>>          text[]
```

**Source:** [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

**Modified :**

```
CREATE TABLE justjson ( doc JSONB)
INSERT INTO justjson VALUES ('{"test": 1, "ch0 gain": 2, "ch1 gain": 3}');
select doc->'ch0 gain' from justjson
```

**Output :** 
2